# How do I map a range?

Tags: rust

I am trying to build objects for every element in a range `n`, so I at the end have a slice of objects.
Cannot seem to figure out the right way, though. Tried:

```rust
[0..n].map(convert_int_to_object)
```

Comment: `let objects: Vec<Object> = (0..n).map(convert_int_to_object).collect();` Did you collect?

Comment: Wrong type of brackets: try `(0..n)`

Comment: `[0..n]` is an array with a single element – the range `0..n`. Arrays have a `map()` method, so `[0..n].map(f)` will call `f` once, with the range as an argument. You probably end up with a slightly confusing error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets `[]` denote arrays in Rust; `a..b` or `(a..b)` denotes a range. So to create an iterator over the range, what you're looking for is:

```rust
(0..n).map(convert_int_to_object)
```

This creates an iterator, but you will need to collect all the new objects into a collection such as a `Vec`. For example:

```rust
fn my_fun(n: i32) -> Vec<MyStruct> {
    (0..n).map(convert_int_to_object).collect()
}
```

You asked for a slice, but you are creating new objects (allocation) so you need to use a `Vec` because it owns the new objects. You can get a slice from a vector `v` with `&v` or `v.as_slice()`.

```rust
let v = my_fun(10);
let slice = v.as_slice();
```